# Performance impact of missing closing tags in HTML

Tags: html, performance, browser

New browsers are intelligent enough to add missing close tags. What is the performance impact due to this? Does browser take more time to parse compared to downloading in decent speed network. <s>Any impact in SEO</s>

In the below snippets, both produce the same output. Bytes are calculated after minification.

**HTML with Missing Tags (164 bytes)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <body>
    <div id=content>
      <h2><s><span>Copy + Paste</s> CODING in Progress (Zzzz...)
    </div>
    <div id=mail>
      <h3><a href=mailto:#>#<title>Home
```

**Valid HTML (227 bytes)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <h2><s><span>Copy + Paste</span></s> CODING in Progress (Zzzz...)</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="mail">
    <h3><a href="mailto:#">#</a></h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[To see a website in action with missing tags](https://venomvendor.com).
Disclaimer: This is my personal website.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both the code snippets:
for one with missing code I got this:
[image: Without Closing Tags]

for one with proper closing tags I got this:
[image: With Closing Tags]

You can eliminate the scripting time, and there is no network request or additional rendering.
And see the overheads in Paint and Render methods.